# what is the recommended mechanism to distribute GRPC clients?

Tags: protocol-buffers, microservices, grpc, service-discovery

I've created a `GRPC` server and would like to distribute "`SDK`" clients in various languages to it.

I can generate the clients relatively easily using the `proto` commands (for example `python`):

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I. --python_out=/tmp/python --grpc_python_out=/tmp/python MyProtoc.proto
```

and similarly for `java/ruby` etc.

This generated code needs to be copied to client applications manually.

I rather not burden my consumers to have to create the generated libs themselves and to integrate them. (especially when adding new functionality to the service)

For instance in the context of `python` it would be more convenient to run something along the lines of

`pip install MyProtoClient`

Are there mechanisms to package the generated libraries to the appropriate canonical package managers (i.e. `pip`/`maven`/`npm` etc.)?

Also, is there a way to call on the service itself to generate the source libraries (or to return the appropriate proto that it is implementing?)

Comment: Are you asking for an easy way to push packages for the RPC client in their respective languages? Right now you'd have to generate them and push them into individual repositories and specify it in the package managers of a location of where to find them. In npm for instance, this is the npm registry, Ruby is the gem registry, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a project solely dedicated to making packages for the generated source. The googleapis' [Artman](https://github.com/googleapis/artman)/[GAPIC Generator](https://github.com/googleapis/gapic-generator) is a project that does so for many languages, but it also does its own code generation and it's mixed together. You can see the [output](https://github.com/google/go-genproto) [for](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python) [some](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby) [languages](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node) (for all of them, look at a particular API, like Pub/Sub).

gRPC servers can expose their definitions via the [reflection API](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-proto/blob/master/grpc/reflection/v1/reflection.proto). There is a pre-built implementation of the service in each language. For example, in Java it is `io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService` and in Go it is `google.golang.org/grpc/reflection`. The service does not return .proto files, but the "descriptors" which are the normal format that protobuf reflection and code generation tools use.